Cómo puedo eliminar la placa de Connect Wallet
Entro a mi página web y me aparece esto, quiero eliminarlo. Es algo de billetera virtual

https://blog.sucuri.net/2024/02/web3-crypto-malware-angel-drainer.html

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
